# Problemas ao relacionar Modelos no CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2

Este e o *Model* `User`

```
class User extends AppModel
{
public $name = 'User';
public $useTable = 'users';
public $displayField = 'name';
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Role' => array(
        'className' => 'Role',
        'foreignKey' => 'role_id'
    )
);
}
```

e este e o *Model* `Role`

```
class Role extends AppModel
{
public $name = 'Role';
public $useTable = 'roles';
public $displayField = 'name';
public $hasMany = array(
        'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);

}
```

porém ao tentar fazer a seguinte requisição

```
$roles = $this->User->Role->find('list');
```

estas são as tabelas referenciadas pelos `Models`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activation_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`role_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `FK_users_roles` (`role_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_users_roles` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

é informado que `Role` é um objeto nulo, alguém sabe informar o que está errado?

Comment: o cake considera que o objeto '$this -> User -> Role' é nulo, por isso estou incluindo o Role nos uses do controle do usuário e  usando-o como um modelo incrementado, porém esta não e a maneira correta :S

Comment: user, neste caso não funciona, porque `User` pertence a `Role` e não o contrário. Você precisa deste find para que?
Se estivesse chamando desta forma, dentro do RolesController funcionaria, mas dentro do UsersControllers não vai funcionar, porque cada usuário só pertence a uma única Role, não teria o que listar neste caso.

Answer (score 1):

Le darei um exemplo de dois *Models* que funcionam perfeitamente para este objetivo

*Model `User.php`*

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * User Model
 *
 * @property Group $Group
 */
class User extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'group_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

*Model `Group.php`*

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Group Model
 *
 * @property User $User
 */
class Group extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: ainda não está funcionando , pode ser algum problema no banco de dados? , o Role deve ter seu Controller?

Comment: Sim, cada um dos models deve ter seu controller

Comment: Poderia colocar a estrutura da sua base de dados na pergunta?

Comment: tá la como ficou os modelos agora e o as tabelas do banco exportadas como script SQL, criei um controller para Role, porém sem metodos, pois não estou interessado em mudar, seus dados devem ser estáticos 1-> ADM, 2-> USER 3 -> PUBLIC

Comment: Não precisa necessariamente de um controller, eventualmente chego a ter 2 ou 3 model para um controller só.